# CDI bean que sobe com a aplicação

Tags: java, tomcat, cdi

Existe alguma forma de iniciar um bean CDI junto da aplicação

Tenho o seguinte bean:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private Helper helper;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        helper.doThings();
    }

}
```

Gostaria que ele fosse iniciado juntamente da aplicação, ao ser deployada.

Estou utilizando o weld-servlet como implementação cdi e o tomcat7:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${weld-servlet.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @Startup? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Startup.html

Comment: Essa annotation é de EJB, estou utilizando só o tomcat 7 com o cdi(weld)

Comment: Que versão do CDI o container Weld em questão implementa? A partir da versão 1.1 do CDI você pode anotar um método para executar durante a inicialização. Exemplo: `public void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object init)`. Parece que isso funciona com o Tomcat 7: https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_tomcat